# Android App Input Numbers enter tick symbol

Tags: android, android-edittext

I tried to write my first app and its okay, everything works.
But there is one thing. The app has 2 edit text elements. In the first one I can enter numbers with the numeric keyboard. On the bottom right is a tick symbol to confirm. In the second edit text element there is another symbol like "->|" that leads me to the first edit text element. But the elements are identical except the id.
How I can change the "->|" symbol to a tick symbol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following in your last `EditText` xml

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```